# Assign CGPoint in UIPanGestureRecognizer from .began to .changed

Tags: ios, swift

Inside my view I have a cardContainerView with a UIPanGestureRecognizer attached to it. Depending on whether the user grabbed the card at the top or bottom half I want to add different rotation angles to my card, which works fine now.

My problem is that the way I implemented it, the user can grab the card at the top (which results in a positive rotation) and slide the card below the location.y threshold I am using, which then results in the card using a negative rotation angle. That causes a jarring jump of the card.

I tried grabbing the location.y in the .began part and assign it to the .changed but apparently I can't do that. It results in a nil value. Anyone have any idea how else I could solve this?

Much appreciated!

```
    //When animation begins
    if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.began {
        print("PAN BEGAN")
        cardContainerViewInitialCenter = cardContainerView.center
        addNewTempCard()
        initialPoint = location
        print("InitialPoint PAN BEGAN \(initialPoint)")
        print("InitialPoint.y PAN BEGAN \(initialPoint.y)")
    }

    //While panning
    else if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.changed {
        print("PAN CHANGED")

        //User grabbed card at top half
        if location.y < view.frame.height/2 {
            print("TOP HALF")

            if translation.x >= 0 && translation.x <= 50 {
                cardContainerView.center = CGPoint(x: cardContainerViewInitialCenter.x + translation.x, y: cardContainerViewInitialCenter.y)
                cardContainerView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: convertedRotationTopPos)
                tempCardView.alpha = convertedNewCardAlphaPos
                tempCardView.transform = view.transform.scaledBy(x: convertedNewCardScaleXPos, y: convertedNewCardScaleYPos)
            }

            else if translation.x > 50 {
                cardContainerView.center = CGPoint(x: cardContainerViewInitialCenter.x + translation.x, y: cardContainerViewInitialCenter.y)
                cardContainerView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: convertedRotationTopPos)
                tempCardView.alpha = convertedNewCardAlphaPos
                tempCardView.transform = view.transform.scaledBy(x: convertedNewCardScaleXPos, y: convertedNewCardScaleYPos)
            }

            else if translation.x < 0 && translation.x >= -50 {
                cardContainerView.center = CGPoint(x: cardContainerViewInitialCenter.x + translation.x, y: cardContainerViewInitialCenter.y)
                cardContainerView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: convertedRotationTopNeg)
                tempCardView.alpha = convertedNewCardAlphaNeg
                tempCardView.transform = view.transform.scaledBy(x: convertedNewCardScaleXNeg, y: convertedNewCardScaleYNeg)
            }

            else if translation.x < -50 {
                cardContainerView.center = CGPoint(x: cardContainerViewInitialCenter.x + translation.x, y: cardContainerViewInitialCenter.y)
                cardContainerView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: convertedRotationTopNeg)
                tempCardView.alpha = convertedNewCardAlphaNeg
                tempCardView.transform = view.transform.scaledBy(x: convertedNewCardScaleXNeg, y: convertedNewCardScaleYNeg)
            }
        }

        //User grabbed card at bottom half
        else if location.y > view.frame.height/2 {
            print("TOP HALF")

            if translation.x >= 0 && translation.x <= 50 {
                cardContainerView.center = CGPoint(x: cardContainerViewInitialCenter.x + translation.x, y: cardContainerViewInitialCenter.y)
                cardContainerView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: convertedRotationBottomPos)
                tempCardView.alpha = convertedNewCardAlphaPos
                tempCardView.transform = view.transform.scaledBy(x: convertedNewCardScaleXPos, y: convertedNewCardScaleYPos)
            }

            else if translation.x > 50 {
                cardContainerView.center = CGPoint(x: cardContainerViewInitialCenter.x + translation.x, y: cardContainerViewInitialCenter.y)
                cardContainerView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: convertedRotationBottomPos)
                tempCardView.alpha = convertedNewCardAlphaPos
                tempCardView.transform = view.transform.scaledBy(x: convertedNewCardScaleXPos, y: convertedNewCardScaleYPos)
            }

            else if translation.x < 0 && translation.x >= -50 {
                cardContainerView.center = CGPoint(x: cardContainerViewInitialCenter.x + translation.x, y: cardContainerViewInitialCenter.y)
                cardContainerView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: convertedRotationBottomNeg)
                tempCardView.alpha = convertedNewCardAlphaNeg
                tempCardView.transform = view.transform.scaledBy(x: convertedNewCardScaleXNeg, y: convertedNewCardScaleYNeg)
            }

            else if translation.x < -50 {
                cardContainerView.center = CGPoint(x: cardContainerViewInitialCenter.x + translation.x, y: cardContainerViewInitialCenter.y)
                cardContainerView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: convertedRotationBottomNeg)
                tempCardView.alpha = convertedNewCardAlphaNeg
                tempCardView.transform = view.transform.scaledBy(x: convertedNewCardScaleXNeg, y: convertedNewCardScaleYNeg)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're not showing where `initialPoint` is defined, but I'm guessing it's a local var of the gesture handler function. If so: make `initialPoint` a member variable of your class, and use it instead of `location` in the `state == .changed` parts of the code.

Comment: Hey, sorry the code above isn't showing my attempt to grab the point in .began. It's the code as it is implemented now which then results in the view jumping. And yup, my attempt was a local var.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should set your intialPoint in the `.began` state. It shouldn't be nil in `.changed`

```
//When animation begins
if sender.state == .began {
    ...
    initialPoint = sender.location(in: self)
}
```

Also I don't think that `else` is really helping you. It shouldn't be `.began` else `.changed`, rather check if `.began` and if `.changed`.

Comment: This worked. Actually I tried something similar but the reason I believed it was nil was because in my attempt I declared the variable incorrectly, causing a force unwrap crash. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class Foo {
  private var initialPoint: CGPoint?

  @objc func panGestureHandler(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    switch gesture.state {
    case .began: self.initialPoint = gesture.location(in: self.view)
    case .changed: 
       if let initial = self.initialPoint {
          // your code from above that deals with .changed goes here, using `initial` as the starting point
       }
    case .ended: self.initialPoint = nil
  }

}
```